# Nested Circular Mean

Tags: statistics, means

Assume this code (written in MatLab). I'm about to calculate average of 50 random angles using Circular Statistics (Circular Mean), with nested averaging method:

```
rm = (rand(5,10) - 0.5) * 12; % generate random numbers in -6 .. 6
av1 = circ_mean(circ_mean(rm)')
av2 = circ_mean(circ_mean(rm')')
```

`av1` and `av2` expected to be the same, but! they are not even close to each other. Is that about implementation?

Comment: You have to look at the program listing in "Circular Statistics Toolbox (Directional Statistics"). I cannot check it, because I haven't this toolbox. A test to be done: if, instead of generating a random "rm" you take rm=ones(5,10), what are the values of av1 and av2 ?

Comment: in this case,  `av1` = `av 2` = `1`